# Populate/adjust new column of DataFrame from another DataFrame column by non-unique first DF column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some DataFrame `df1` without index like this:

```
[
    "event_id", "cat_id", "clm_1", ..., "clm_n"
     123,        345,     "qwe",   ..., "asd"
     999,        222,     "sss",   ..., "ddd"
     ...
     333,        345,     "qqq",   ..., "ooo"
]
```

And another DataFrame `df2` (`cat_id` is index):

```
[
    "cat_id", "features"
    345, "cat,dog"
    567, "chupacabra"
    ...
]
```

`cat_id` in `df1` is non-unique, but it is unique in `df2` and it is an `index`

How can I add new `features` column to `df1` and populate it from `df2` by `cat_id`?

Expected result is:

```
[
    "event_id", "cat_id", "clm_1", ..., "clm_n", "features"
     123,        345,     "qwe",   ..., "asd",   "cat,dog"
     999,        222,     "sss",   ..., "ddd",   None
     ...
     333,        345,     "qqq",   ..., "ooo",   "cat,dog"
]
```

Comment: You can use the pandas `merge` functionality

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='cat_id', how='left')`